# Health or Status endpoints in spring rest

Tags: spring, rest, http, spring-mvc, monitoring

I have a bunch of rest services built using spring mvc,rest . each of the services talk to various underlying services/systems . Is there a generic way I can globally enable something like a /health or a /status endpoint on all my services. I am looking for something like a @ControllerAdvice that I may use to collect some information of the service and tell the user some custom statistics of my services.Can I use spring boot actuator with a non spring boot application and accomplish that

Answer (score 1):

You can add Dropwizard Metrics (https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/) to your project, which contains a lot of the default statistics and you can add custom metrics to it. Then this statistics can be retrieved using single endpoint url.